# Why does power function in c take longer than expected for large numbers

Tags: c++, c

Where am i getting it wrong? 
The pow(double,double) function in c/c++ runs in O(log n) time which means it shouldn't take a noticeable time to calculate the power for long numbers. I wrote a function to calculate the a^b mod m in logarithmic time, which again takes longer than expected.
The function is defined as:

```
float pow(float a,float n,float m){
  float temp,temp2;
  if(n==0)
    return 1;
  temp=pow(a,n/2,m);
  if(fmod(n,2)==0){
    if(temp>m){
      temp=fmod(temp,m);
    }
    temp2=temp*temp;
    if(temp2>m)
      temp2=fmod(temp2,m);
    return temp2;
  }
  else{
    if(temp>m){
      temp=fmod(temp,m);
    }
    temp2=temp*temp*a;
    if(temp2>m)
      temp2=fmod(temp2,m);
    return temp2;
  }
}
```

If I call pow(10^9,10^9,123) I am expecting it to run in ~ O(log(10^9)) complexity and hence finish under 1 second on my computer(O(10^8) runs in 1 sec). But its taking like forever. Same happens with std::pow(double,double).

Comment: you're recursing until a float, repeatedly divided by 2, becomes 0? Really?

Comment: I am sorry about that. But its not the issue. I am passing only integer values for n. Will update now. @hobbs

Comment: what's the complexity of `fmod`?

Comment: Usage of big-O notation is not quite correct here.  O(10^8) is the same thing as O(1).

Comment: Naming a function the same as a standard function is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, repeatedly dividing a float by 2 will only complete when you run out of exponent.  (For fun, try passing in `1.0f/0.0f`.)

```
int func(float n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return 1 + func(n / 2);
}
```

On my system, `func(1.0f)` gives 151.  This is probably not what you want!

You want this:

```
float pow(float a, int n, float m) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1.0f;
    float t = pow(a, n / 2, m);
    return fmodf((n & 1) ? t*t*a : t*t, m);
}
```

Note that `pow()` is quite different.  The definition for `pow()` is closer to this:

```
float powf(float x, float y) {
    if (...) {
        // faster, special case versions
    }
    return expf(logf(x) * y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the problem persists when I call the pow function of the math library with values larger than 10^9.

Comment: @jmathews: Can you show us how this happens?  On my system, `pow()` is very fast.  What math library are you using?  (Or what compiler/OS are you using)

Comment: Can you please try pow(123123123,123123123). Of course it will overflow but does it return a value fast?

Comment: I get: `0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.003 total` for the amount of time it takes to compute that.  This is with optimizations turned off, and the arguments to `pow` taken from `argv`.

Comment: @jmathews: I ran it in a loop 10^8 times, without optimization, and recorded an average time of about 62 nanoseconds per call to `pow()`.

Comment: I just restarted my system and it works now. I was declaring a large array (globally) from the system heap. Its working now! Although I dont understand why no error was thrown when it dint find the space. 
And should I take down the question?

Comment: (1) declaring an array won't cause it to use heap space (2) allocating an array won't cause it to consume memory (3) restarting your system shouldn't have an effect unless it killed a process which was hogging all your CPU cores (4) `pow()` uses a negligible amount of memory, and what memory it does use is on the stack, so if you run out it should crash your program hard.

Answer (score 0):

The only condition to end the recursion is if n is zero.  That is only ever achieved if continual dividing by 2 gives a zero result (which basically means underflowing the float type).   That takes a while for large values.